# How can I delete files from recycle bin in windows? python

Tags: python, recycle-bin

I'm trying to delete files that are in the recycle bin by using python, but i can't find a way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: What OS? Please do not assume everyone know your environments. Also please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @wizzup You are referring to a question asking for file deletion, not emptying a recycle bin.

Answer (score 15):

For the Windows OS you can use the [winshell](https://github.com/tjguk/winshell) module and it's [empty](https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recycle-bin.html#winshell.ShellRecycleBin.empty) method.

Emptying the recycle bin is as easy as:

```
import winshell
winshell.recycle_bin().empty(confirm=False, show_progress=False, sound=False)
```

See some [examples here](http://programtalk.com/python-examples/winshell.recycle_bin/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a Windows shell module wrapped by PyWin32 that does this, assuming the question is for Windows.

http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/shell__SHEmptyRecycleBin_meth.html