# Cache error when using pytesseract for OCR

Tags: python, imagemagick, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to use pytesseract OCR to extract text from all the PDFs in a directory, but I am getting an error message that there is not enough space on my device.

I would like to delete each image from the cache after it is no longer required, as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454582/cache-error-while-doing-ocr-on-a-directory-of-pdfs-in-python) was advised to do, but I can't find anything in the [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) documentation explaining how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi

def extract_text_from_image(path):
    pdfFile = wi(filename = path, resolution = 300)
    image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')  

    imageBlobs = []
    for img in image.sequence:
        imgPage = wi(image = img)
        imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

    extract = []
    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang = 'eng')
        extract.append(text)

    return extract
```

Here is the error message:

```
CacheError: unable to extend cache 'C:/Users/b00kgrrl/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-11952ORBzkae3wXX_18': No space left on device @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3889
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself using code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834731/how-to-delete-a-file-by-extension-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089399/how-can-i-delete-files-from-recycle-bin-in-windows-python):

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
import winshell

def extract_text_from_image(path):

    pdfFile = wi(filename = path, resolution = 300)
    image = pdfFile.convert('jpeg')

    tempdir = r"C:\Users\b00kgrrl\AppData\Local\Temp"
    cache = os.listdir( tempdir )

    imageBlobs = []
    for img in image.sequence:
        imgPage = wi(image = img)
        imageBlobs.append(imgPage.make_blob('jpeg'))

    extract = []
    for imgBlob in imageBlobs:
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang = 'eng')
        extract.append(text)

        for item in cache:
            if item.endswith(".jpg") or item.startswith("magick-"):
                os.remove( os.path.join( tempdir, item ) )
                winshell.recycle_bin().empty(confirm=False, show_progress=False, sound=False)

    return extract
```